# R - Subscript out of bounds when reading jpeg

Tags: r, loops, jpeg, bounds, subscript

I'm trying to read all the jpg files from a folder and store it in a vector.

To make it simple, I'm trying to read only two images as a start.

First, I create a list, which gives me a character vector of 1:2.

```
original_files <- list.files("D:/User/Documents/Folder", pattern="*jpg$", full.name=F)
```

Which results in:

```
[1] "File1.jpg" "File2.jpg"
```

Then I create an empty list and a for loop to read them all and store them:

```
empty_list=list()
    for (i in original_files) 
    {
      img <- readJPEG(original_files[[i]])
      empty_list[[i]] <- img
  }
```

It executes the function returning the following error:

```
Error in gabor_ori_files[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I don't really understand why I get this message or how to solve it. I've tried to use lapply instead of a for loop, and it doesn't work either.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the way you define your for argument.

```
for (i in original_files)
```

implies that i should take the values in original_files, meaning "File1.jpg" "File2.jpg". In doing on the first loop you are asking for

```
img <- readJPEG(original_files[["File1.jpg"]])
```

However, none of the elements in your vector has the *name* "File1.jpg", they have the *value* of "File1.jpg"

The best way to avoid this kind of confusion is to always loop over the positions instead of names. In order words, using

```
for (i in 1:length(original_files))
```

It should work then